# Google password compromised?

Tags: google-play-store, security, google-account

A few days ago I noticed my phone notify me about my Google play account as if I had changed my password. Yesterday I found out I had been infected with a rootkit and a packet sniffer. I was able to access my Google account. Found no weird logins to my account. So I checked "Devices" and it said "Unable to connect to phone, last time connected April the 6th". So it means someone did something to my account? I mean it's not that easy to log out of my account on my phone is it? I  changed my password and my password rest email, so I should be safe?

Comment: Packet sniffer on your laptop? Or the phone? You can easily remove Google accounts from your phone under `Settings > Accounts & Sync`. Your phone should have asked for your new password when you changed it (you didn't mention it explicitly.) If it didn't ask, then your phone truly cannot connect to the Internet (Google), or the rootkit prevented the password change. Beware!

Comment: For an optimal security, I'll recommend you to enable the two-factors authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should immediately factory reset your phone, then go to Google and go through the [Google Security Check-up](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount) and verify EVERYTHING (don't skip any checks), and I would also recommend enabling 2-Step Authentication.

After that, setup your phone again and make sure to enable a lockscreen password, and possibly device encryption as well. Do not enable "Unknown Sources" without somekind of quality security package installed.

I would also go through everything on the [Sign In & Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) page and look for any anomalies.

Comment: Yeah I thought about resetting my phone, too.

Comment: Personally, I would factory default then change my password again. Better safe than sorry, but a factory reset is essential IMHO.